# how to forward Form data to iFrame containing another form?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css

I have a form having some hidden fields and when I submit form I need to forward that data to a page which is iFrame, I am not able to figure out it.

That iFrame is just another form.

It need not pop up just flow in same page.

Answer (score 1):

your iframe should have a name

```
 <iframe name=blah>
 </iframe>
```

your link should target that name

```
  <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="blah">
```

If you want to use in the form should do this

```
 <form action="do_stuff.aspx" method="post" target="blah">
     <input type="submit" value="Do Stuff!" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends:
From one side, if your `<iframe>` content (or `src`) comes from the same domain then you should be able to manipulate it using `jQuery` library.

On the other hand, if your `<iframe>` content (or `src`) comes from another domain, then you'll are restricted with the operations you could do on the `<iframe>` due to security policy that should prevent cross-domain/cross-protocol manipulations from taking action.

You may provide more information,